# VIM substitute first occurence

Tags: vim, format, substitution

I have a text file with lines in the following format:

```
some text:23: class Headphones : Device { // comment this is a comment
```

What I want to do is replace first occurrence of `:stuff:` with `:stuff:,` (add an extra comma afterwards)
The line would then become:

```
some text:23:, class Headphones : Device { // comment this is a comment
```

What I have tried is `%s/:.*:/&/` however the search is matching `:23: class Headphones :` and not the first occurrence... what is going on and how can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your match non-greedy using `\{-}`:

```
%s/:.\{-}:/&,/
```

Comment: You can drop the back references and just use `&` for the match. So the shortened substitute would be `:%s/:.\{-}:/&,`